# Bi-directional ScrollView

Tags: android

I'm curious if anyone has run into the same problem as me. I have an image that I can manipulate with pinch zooming. I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally and vertically when the image is too large for the screen. I've accomplished this with a ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView combo. But this implementation leads to clunky behavior. Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Comment: Multiple Google engineers have said that the `ScrollView`/`HorizontalScrollView` combo will result in problems (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/c50acbe68ec98174/7d234358e2a57775 and http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/c05925aca7479d18).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to implement a custom component that allows scrolling in both directions, as it appears `ScrollView` only supports vertical scrolling. You should review the Android documentation for the `Scroller` class, found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html). I cannot recommend against multiple scrollviews enough. This will almost always result in "clunky" unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own class for this. There is no already built solution. If you've already written pinch zooming, scrolling should be much easier.