# Implementing horizontal and vertical scroll at a time in a custom list view

Tags: android

I am developing a custom list view and putting data using a custom adapter.Normally the list scrolls vertically and it is working fine. But I need to show some more data in each row and need to scroll the list view horizontally also. 
So, my query would be is it possible to club both horizontal and vertical scroll in a custom list view ?

Please help.

Regards,
Prithwish

Comment: Multiple questions on this topic have been asked before: http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239646/bi-directional-scrollview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866499/two-directional-scroll-view just to name the first results in google. Take a look there

Answer (score 1):

If you say ScrollView, by default it is Vertical Scroll, You can implement your requirement by using ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView as follows:
RelativeLayout......

ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

Your next child layout//This is mandatory to place a layout here

/HorizontalScrollView
/ScrollView
/RelativeLayout

Hope that helps